# renderでのデプロイ失敗時の原因が見つからない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render.com

他のサイトでも質問したのですが、回答がなかなかつかず、こちらでも質問させていただきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/61mpn6dkyaxe50

#### 実現したいこと

render.comでデプロイをしたのですがデプロイに失敗しました。
原因を知りたいのですが、見つけることができません。
エラーや原因を見つけるコツや、要因などありますでしょうか？

Gistにエラーログを記入したので、確認して頂けたら幸いです。

[エラーログ全文 (Gist)](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/2J445/dbf44b94834975fa4c0b13ea032c3796/raw/00b01bc1f7890bae317eeb65d28dce3b68ca267a/gistfile1.txt)

**エラーログ (抜粋):**

```
Feb 11 04:11:53 PM  ==> Cloning from https://github.com/2J445/tsunageru...
Feb 11 04:11:55 PM  ==> Checking out commit 116bfd7c84355336c3b9843a951afccebbb9d5e4 in branch master
Feb 11 04:11:59 PM  ==> Detected Ruby version 3.0.0
Feb 11 04:12:09 PM  Updating rubygems-update
Feb 11 04:12:09 PM  Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.4.6
Feb 11 04:12:09 PM  Installing RubyGems 3.4.6
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM    Successfully built RubyGem
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM    Name: bundler
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM    Version: 2.4.6
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM    File: bundler-2.4.6.gem
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  Bundler 2.4.6 installed
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  RubyGems 3.4.6 installed
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  Regenerating binstubs
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  Regenerating plugins
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  

～～～

Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  RubyGems installed the following executables:
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM      /opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/gem
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM      /opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM      /opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundler
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  
Feb 11 04:12:10 PM  RubyGems system software updated
Feb 11 04:12:15 PM  ==> Running build command './bin/render-build.sh'...
Feb 11 04:12:15 PM  Your Gemfile lists the gem rails-i18n (>= 0) more than once.
Feb 11 04:12:15 PM  You should probably keep only one of them.
Feb 11 04:12:15 PM  Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
Feb 11 04:12:15 PM  While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Feb 11 04:12:18 PM  Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........

～～～

Feb 11 04:14:03 PM  Bundle complete! 33 Gemfile dependencies, 93 gems now installed.
Feb 11 04:14:03 PM  Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Feb 11 04:14:03 PM  Bundled gems are installed into `/opt/render/project/.gems`
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  rake aborted!
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:203:in `rescue in _decrypt'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:180:in `_decrypt'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:154:in `decrypt_and_verify'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:92:in `decrypt'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `read'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:309:in `method_missing'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:24:in `key_exists?'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:10:in `find'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:37:in `block in <class:Engine>'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/src/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  <internal:/opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  <internal:/opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/bin/bundle:113:in `load'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/bin/bundle:113:in `<main>'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  Caused by:
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:190:in `key='
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:190:in `_decrypt'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:154:in `decrypt_and_verify'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:92:in `decrypt'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `read'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:309:in `method_missing'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:24:in `key_exists?'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:10:in `find'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:37:in `block in <class:Engine>'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/src/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  <internal:/opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  <internal:/opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/bin/bundle:113:in `load'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  /opt/render/project/.gems/bin/bundle:113:in `<main>'
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  Tasks: TOP => environment
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  ==> Build failed 
Feb 11 04:14:06 PM  ==> Generating container image from build. This may take a few minutes...
```

#### 前提

下記の記事を参考にデプロイを進めていました。

[Render.comでRailsアプリの本番環境を作成する方法をどこよりも優しく伝える！ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ysk91_engineer/items/b7db950f4739fa896f57)
[RailsアプリをRender.comでデプロイする手順まとめ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/koki_73/items/60b327a586129d157f38)

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

githubに反映させてデプロイを試したところ失敗したと表示されましたが、原因を突き止められません。
エラー箇所を探しているのですが、見つかりませんでした。

#### 試したこと

エラー箇所を探そうとしたのですが、わかりませんでした。

デプロイに対しての質問が分からないので、こういう情報を載せてくれると助かる等、教えて頂けたら幸いです。

#### 該当のソースコード

puma.rb

```
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 4 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
preload_app!
```

production.rb

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present? || ENV['RENDER'].present?←追記
```

renderibuild.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# exit on error
set -o errexit

bundle install
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
bundle exec rake assets:clean
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

render.yaml

```
databases:
  - name: アプリの名前を記入しています。
    databaseName: アプリの名前を記入しています。
    user: アプリの名前を記入しています。
    region: singapore

services:
  - type: web
    name: アプリの名前を記入しています。
    env: ruby
    region: singapore
    buildCommand: "./bin/render-build.sh"
    startCommand: "bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb"
    envVars:
      - key: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
        fromDatabase:
          name: render_app
          property: connectionString
      - key: <%= ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'] %>
        sync: false
```

.env.production

```
DB_PASSWORD = '伏せています。'
DATABASE_URL = '伏せています。'
RAILS_MASTER_KEY = '伏せています。'
```

Comment: ログの前半は恐らく CHANGELOG、途中にはインストールされた Gemfile のログなので、エラーには直接関係無さそうでした。特に重要そうな部分のみを抜粋して質問中に直接貼り付けておきました。

Comment: エラーの "ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes" に注目して web 検索してみると、関連しそうなページがいくつかヒットします。 [rails アプリを Renderにデプロイ時に　ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes が出る](https://teratail.com/questions/tk3l56t5q52vis)

Comment: デプロイ成功しました。config/master.keyファイルの中のキーをrenderのダッシュボードからRAILS_MASTER_KEYのキーと同じにしてgitにプッシュし、デプロイしたところ成功と表示されました。

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄で終わらせずに、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

デプロイ成功しました。config/master.keyファイルの中のキーをrenderのダッシュボードからRAILS_MASTER_KEYのキーと同じにしてgitにプッシュし、デプロイしたところ成功と表示されました。